# How to create JSON tree and nested nodes in Firebase using AngularFire2

Tags: json, angular, firebase, angularfire2

There is no proper documentation for AngularFire2 v5, so I don't know where am i supposed to learn from, but here it's only for Firestore. I don't use firestore, I use Firebase Realtime Database. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/tree/master/docs

However, I'm pretty new to it, and I'm looking how can I store data in a collection, that would look something like this:

```
nepal-project-cffb1: 
   users: 
      userid: 
        email: "lajmis@mail.com"
        score: 1
```

My function now looks like this:

```
this._db.list("users/" + "id").set({
      email: this.user,
      score: this.score
    })
```

but it doesn't work, I get `Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.` error. There are a bunch of syntaxes, like `.ref` `.list` and i don't know which one to use.

Comment: I was hoping for example how to store and not to retrieve using valueChanges(). And I'm asking for a help how to do that following my provided data structure in OP. This doc is not beginner friendly and thus I'm asking for help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an entire section of the AngularFire guide [dedicated to RTDB](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2#realtime-database), so I'm confused by the statement that there is no real documentation. Typically you would use `valueChanges()` to create a list observer as described [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#retrieve-data) for reading, and set() is covered [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#replacing-items-in-the-list-using-set).

So as that doc illustrates, you need to pass the key of the record to be modified, and also the data to be changed when you call it.

```
this._db.list("users").set("id", {...});
```

But if you aren't monitoring the collection, you can also just use [db.object](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md) directly:

```
this._db.object("users/id").set({...});
```

One aspect that may not be immediately intuitive with AngularFire is that it's mainly an adapter pattern intended to take away some of the boilerplate of ferrying data between your Angular model and your Firebase servers.

If you aren't syncing data (downloading a local copy) then there's no reason to use AngularFire here. You can simply call the Firebase SDK directly and avoid the overhead of subscribing to remote endpoints:

```
firebase.database().ref("users/id").set({...});
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I was pretty confused at first whether I should use Firebase SDK or AngularFire2 and what's the difference, but in my case I see SDK works just fine.